# Cannot resolve response 404 error in Java Spring Boot starter project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using a `RestController` like this one:

```
@RestController
public class xxxController {

@Autowired
private xxxService MyService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/addxxx", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public XxxModel additionY(@RequestBody xxmodel XyXmodel {
    return MyService.addValuexx(XyXmodel);
}
```

I'm often getting the following error:

```
Response
404
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 21 Nov 2017 07:37:53 GMT
{
    "timestamp": 1511249873832,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error beacuse you don't have a mapping for the path `/`.

What you created is a mapping for `/addxxx`. So the address you should call is (if you're running on localhost, say port 8080) `http://localhost:8080/addxxx`